# App to automatically download and view a list of web pages offline

Tags: browser, offline

I have a very specific workflow that I can't find a simple solution for.

I want to be able to make a list of web pages to read offline. Not articles, whole web pages. And I want to keep them up-to-date.

I really want an app for Android (my phone: Galaxy S2) that does the following.

1. Lets me enter a list of webpages and maintain that list.
2. Hit a button in the app, and it'll update every page on that list and store a complete offline copy so I can pursue it while on the train.
3. Still maintain links, so I can click on them (so, no PDFs or whatever).
4. Optionally have the ability to set readable fonts.
5. Even better, if there was a way to export this list and modify it on my computer, share it, manipulate it etc. (or if there were a web serivce with an API).

My personal use case is very simple. I'm a Wikipedia administrator, and there are a variety of public noticeboards for discussions of interest to administrators, like the [administrators' noticeboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aAN) and the usually drama-filled [administrators' noticeboard for incidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aANI). I'd say there's probably about 10-20 pages I want. I'd rather like it if I could get either my phone or iPad, wake up in the morning, push the "update" button, go brush my teeth and by the time I'm leaving for my commute, have all the pages up-to-date and readable on the train.

Answers you may suggest that are wrong up-front:

- Instapaper/Readability/Read It Later: those are for saving things broadly like newspaper articles for later reading. They are optimized for extracting text. They are fantastic, but don't actually meet the use case.
- Some combination of Evernote, Google Docs, AppleScript/Python/Ruby/Perl and sticky tape: I've got enough pain and broken software in my life already.
- Anything involving RSS. Again, look at the links above. There are RSS feeds for individual changes to the page, but I'm interested in saving the whole page, not getting an RSS feed.

Basically what I'm looking for is an Android version of what they referred to as an "offline browser" back in the early days of the web. Is there such a thing that doesn't suck?

Comment: I originally asked this on SuperUser. Apparently, questions about Android software are out of scope on a site that allows questions on "computer hardware and software". I also am interested in iOS software that does the same thing - so I've asked on the Apple SE - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39381/ipad-app-to-automatically-download-and-view-a-list-of-web-pages-offline

Comment: App suggestions are generally off-topic on this site, but the general idea behind this question is quite useful - how to use offline browsing on Android.  If you can edit it to sound less like an app shopping request, it would be great.

Answer (score 3):

[Offline Browser](https://market.android.com/details?id=it.nikodroid.offline) app sounds exactly like what you are looking for.  You can specify a list of web pages to download for offline reading, along with a per-page configurable link depth (so that it doesn't just pull down the home page.)

Answer (score 0):

Its too late, but might help somebody landing on this page. I using Android PaperSpan app for this and it downloads original whole page (no article/pdf). So can click on a link from  offline page if Internet is back. To read them on computer, I copy from phone to computer, then can read as any saved web page. Hope this helps.

Comment: How does this keep them up to date?