# What is the best way to get the Android SDK reference offline on my Android device?

Tags: downloading, android-sdk, offline, documentation

I want to study the Android API on my phone during my frequent and long metro rides (where I cannot connect to the internet).

What would be the best way to make the documentation available (I would appreciate being able to use a search option and an index)? Is copying all the documentation files from my PC to my Android device the best thing to do? Is there any serious app that could provide these features?

Comment: It seems like you could do this with something like [storing web-pages for offline reading](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/app-to-automatically-download-and-view-a-list-of-web-pages-offline), unless you're trying to get the documentation in some specific non-HTML format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the documentation of Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0) by the **SDK Manager**.

SDK manager-->Android 4.0.3 (API15)-->Documentation for Android SDK

It will download all the documentation in `<android-sdk>\docs` of your PC.

Comment: I guess it's the best thing to do. I hope I can use the search function using this method.

Comment: You can search for files, even with the integrated google search, if you install Solid Explorer a new nice File explorer app for android (no I don't work there/know them etc) From the description: _Indexed search, also available from the system (that means that you can search for files from the Google Search widget/app)_  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solid.explorer

Comment: Yes, you can use the search and it works same as the time you are online.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the solution you are looking for exactly but an alternative way would be to use the code completion feature of the [AIDE app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui), an Android IDE running on Android.

Plus you can code during your metro rides and even meetings :)

Comment: Ah yeah, AIDE is a very nice app too, +1 for your idea !